# discord bot (-function like school bells)

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

My idea was to make discord bot that will be ringing at the same time like bells at our scholl.
At the start of the day I write to chat !ring for start timing my lessons, but it doesn´t work.

**Here is my code:**

```
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.utils import get
import datetime


TOKEN = '####'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.command()
async def ring(ctx):
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%X")
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    lessons = {"1.lesson": "8:10:00",
              "2.lesson": "9:05:00",
              "3.lesson": "10:00:00",
              "4.lesson": "11:00:00",
              "5.lesson": "11:55:00",
              "6.lesson": "13:00:00",
              "7.lesson": "13:55:00"}
    await ctx.send(now)
    await ctx.send(ctx.message.author.nick)
    await ctx.send("activated!")

    while 1:
        datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%X")
        # 1.hodina
        if datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%X") == (lessons["6.lesson"]):
            await ctx.send("crrrrrrrrrrr")
            await ctx.send("crrrrrrrrrrr")
            await channel.connect()
            voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            source = FFmpegPCMAudio('alarm.mp3')
            voice.play(source)
            await asyncio.sleep(14)
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
            start = 1
            i = 0
            break

    while start == 1:
        # 2.lesson
        if i == 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(3300)
            await channel.connect()
            voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            source = FFmpegPCMAudio('alarm.mp3')
            voice.play(source)
            await asyncio.sleep(14)
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
            i = 1

        # 3.lesson
        if i == 1:
            await asyncio.sleep(3300)
            await channel.connect()
            voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            source = FFmpegPCMAudio('alarm.mp3')
            voice.play(source)
            await asyncio.sleep(14)
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
            i = 2

        # 4.lesson
        if i == 2:
            await asyncio.sleep(3600)
            await channel.connect()
            voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            source = FFmpegPCMAudio('alarm.mp3')
            voice.play(source)
            await asyncio.sleep(14)
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
            i = 3

        # 5.lesson
        if i == 3:
            await asyncio.sleep(3300)
            await channel.connect()
            voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            source = FFmpegPCMAudio('alarm.mp3')
            voice.play(source)
            await asyncio.sleep(14)
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
            i = 4

        # 6.lesson
        if i == 4:
            await asyncio.sleep(3900)
            await channel.connect()
            voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            source = FFmpegPCMAudio('alarm.mp3')
            voice.play(source)
            await asyncio.sleep(14)
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
            i = 5

        # 7.lesson
        if i == 5:
            await asyncio.sleep(3300)
            await channel.connect()
            voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            source = FFmpegPCMAudio('alarm.mp3')
            voice.play(source)
            await asyncio.sleep(14)
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
            start == 0


client.run(TOKEN)
```

**Here is what console says:**

```
Bot is ready
Bot is ready
Ignoring exception in command ring:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vitek\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Pycharm Projects\Discord_Bots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 329, in connect
    await utils.sane_wait_for(futures, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\vitek\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Pycharm Projects\Discord_Bots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 352, in sane_wait_for
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError()
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vitek\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Pycharm Projects\Discord_Bots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/vitek/OneDrive/Dokumenty/Pycharm Projects/Discord_Bots/test.py", line 38, in ring
    await channel.connect()
  File "C:\Users\vitek\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Pycharm Projects\Discord_Bots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1122, in connect
    await voice.connect(timeout=timeout, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\vitek\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Pycharm Projects\Discord_Bots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 331, in connect
    await self.disconnect(force=True)
  File "C:\Users\vitek\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Pycharm Projects\Discord_Bots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 423, in disconnect
    if self.ws:
AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'ws'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vitek\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Pycharm Projects\Discord_Bots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\vitek\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Pycharm Projects\Discord_Bots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vitek\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Pycharm Projects\Discord_Bots\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'ws'
```

*Have you got some tips how to solve this ?
I will really apreciate some support Thank you very much.*